# how to update the object value on click using javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
const obj = {'name1':true, 'name2': false, 'name3':true}
```

I have a `onclick` function in that I will be getting the `name` based on this `name` I need to change the object name value if it is `true` i need to change to `false` if it `false` change to `true`

Note: this should be happen based on the click only

my output should be

```
const obj = {'name1':true, 'name2': true, 'name3':true}
```

Comment: Add a listener click event of element  and then update the value.

Comment: Value of `name1` does not change. Can you please explain the logic

Comment: Maybe you should have shown some HTML code . Did you write any JavaScript code that attempted to solve it?

Comment: Please provide the code you have already tried with

Comment: Please don't just copy/paste your code.  You need to create a **[mcve]** so we can help you.

Comment: I not have any idea how to do this

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal `name1` will not change

Comment: Besides, there cannot be two keys with the same identifier on the same object. Hence, `name2` can exist only once.

Comment: @briosheje sorry my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is just to [`addEventListener`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) to every `input`, and "duplicate" the current state to the target object. Here is a code example with comments:

```js
const obj = {
  'name1': true,
  'name2': false,
  'name3': true
};

/* Get all inputs */
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

/* Add "click" listener to every input */
inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('click', () => {
  /* Store current state of clicked input to target object property */
  obj[input.name] = input.checked;
  console.log(obj);
}));
```

```css
input {
  margin: 12px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="name1" checked />
<input type="checkbox" name="name2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="name3" checked />
```

Comment: is it possible in es6 ?

Comment: @techie18, why not? It's a ES6 example, arrow functions and `const` are parts of ES6 specification.

Answer (score 0):

> Try the below code as well as concept, may be solve your issue :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select onchange="test(this)">
      <option value="name1"> Name1 </option>
      <option value="name2"> Name2 </option>
      <option value="name3"> Name3 </option>
  </select>
  <script>
    const obj = {'name1':true, 'name2': false, 'name3' :true};
function test(e){
   console.log("Before");
   console.log(obj);
   console.log("Name select");
   console.log(e.value);
   obj[e.value]=  !  obj[e.value];
  console.log("After");
   console.log(obj);
  
}
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```